# Date picker custom component using GWT

Tags: gwt, calendar

I need to create Custom component which should have Label to store say select date then text box and image, by clicking image calendar should pop up and by selecting date the date should be filled in text box. and it should be re usable many panels or on the same panel. please provide me some examples if you have.
thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: Why dont you want to use http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwDatePicker?

Answer (score 1):

See this component library [GWT Bootstrap](http://gwtbootstrap.github.com/#datepicker) this is a implementation in gwt of Twitter Bootstrap